# django uwsgi: Server Error (500) - while accessing view model without "q" parameter

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-20.04

I started facing an issue since upgrading my server from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It seems that I'm encountering an issue (`Server Error (500)`) with only one model, specifically with the URI `/admin/mymodule/mymodel/`. Please refer `uwsgi` logs below:

```
[pid: 27771|app: 0|req: 4/8] 192.168.1.101 () {72 vars in 1623 bytes} [Fri May 26 06:11:11 2023] GET /admin/mymodule/mymodel/ => generated 145 bytes in 210 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 6 headers in 184 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

But when trying the same URI with query parameter (`/admin/mymodule/mymodel/?all=&q=2022-12-19`), it is working fine. Please refer `uwsgi` logs below:

```
[pid: 27768|app: 0|req: 3/9] 192.168.1.101 () {70 vars in 1627 bytes} [Fri May 26 06:11:15 2023] GET /admin/mymodule/mymodel/?all=&q=2022-12-19 => generated 100205 bytes in 1013 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 9 headers in 463 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 27770|app: 0|req: 3/10] 192.168.1.101 () {68 vars in 1468 bytes} [Fri May 26 06:11:16 2023] GET /admin/jsi18n/ => generated 3187 bytes in 12 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 189 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

I don't understand the behavior as I'm able to access all other view models and custom views successfully without any issues. And able to access this view with any query parameter value.

I have already tried some steps to address the issue, but no luck:

- Restart uwsgi service
- Restart nginx
- Restart Virtual Machine

Any insights on what could be causing this issue or if there is anything that might be missing? It would also be helpful to know if anyone else has encountered a similar issue and how it was resolved. Any input or guidance on how to address this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you run it with debug=TRUE to get detailled error trace?

Comment: @Razenstein Thank you. This was a really good point. When tried found `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1038, 'Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size')` error. 

And I am very well aware of how to fix this issue by configuring `sort_buffer_size` value in `mysqld.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0):

The lesson I learned from this is to use `DEBUG = True` when you are facing some issue with Django.

In my case, I got the below error while using `DEBUG = True`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1811, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 320, in _query
    self._do_get_result(db)
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 145, in _do_get_result
    self._result = result = self._get_result()
  File "/usr/local/share/track_vm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 352, in _get_result
    return self._get_db().store_result()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1038, 'Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size')
```

To resolve an issue, I set `sort_buffer_size` value in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf` file.

```
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 4M
```

I think we are facing this issue because as part of the Ubuntu upgrade, we also upgraded our MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0.33. This might have removed MySQL configurations set earlier.

Once again, @Razenstein, thank you very much.